# Sidebar that appears when i hover it

Tags: html, css

I would like to make my sidebar appear when i am overlapping it. I've tried that using css but it didn't work. How can i make it work?

HTML CODE:

```
<div class="body">
    <div class="container">
    </div>
    <div class="bar-open">
    <div class="bar" id="bar">
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <h1>Hola</h1>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS CODE:

```
.bar-open {
    position:absolute;
    float: left;
    width: 0.5%;
    height: 100%;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.bar {
    color: white;
    position:absolute;
    float: left;
    background-color: #F89406;
    width: 12%;
    height: 100%;
    display: none;
}
.bar-open:hover .bar {
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change .bar-open visibility to visible

```
  .bar-open {
    position:absolute;
    float: left;
    width: 0.5%;
    height: 100%;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/bkq5ksx4/2/)

Comment: Feedback: I put a lot of effort into helping a new user format their question, with the intention of encouraging them to do their own homework with a well-asked question. The result of [helping them cheat on that homework](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40197366) is they will hand in your work, and they will [delete their question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40197174), making all the editing work redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Change you selector to this. The + sign selects the sibling.

```
 .bar-open {
    float: left;
    width: 0.5%;
    height: 100%;
}
.bar {
    color: white;
    float: left;
    background-color: #F89406;
    width: 12%;
    height: 100%;
    display: none;
}
.bar-open:hover+.bar {
    display: block;
}
```